# Loop to Calculate Price

Tags: php, loops, woocommerce, e-commerce

trying to create a loop to calculate a price but cant get my head around how to do it.

```
$sell = ($price*$vat);
$profit = ((($price*$vat)*0.04)+0.2);

function newSell($price1){

   $price1 = $price1 + 0.10;
   return $price;
}

do {
     $price1 = newSell($price);
     $profit = ((($price1*$vat)*0.04)+0.2);
} while ($profit  < 0);
```

$price is the price of my item
$sell is my starting price. 
$profit is the calcualtion to work out my profit.

What i want to do is look around and if my profit is less than 0 i want to add 10p (0.10) to my price and then recalculate my profit and evaluate it again. Want to keep going until my profit is above 1 at which point it stops and my new selling price has been set.

Cant for the life of me get my head around this!

Many thanks

Comment: where are you getting 0.04 and 0.2 for the profit and what is the code doing wrong?

Comment: `$price1 = $price1 + 0.10;  return $price;` I think you meant to return price1?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all your newSell function should look like this:

```
function newSell($price) {
    return $price + .1
}
```

It currently does nothing.

Second, are you sure this is the way you should be trying to solve this? It seems to me like you are just trying to solve for $profit >= 1. It's a simple equation that takes no loops whatsoever.

Apparently `$profit = $price * $vat * .04 + .2`, so you are really looking at `1 <= $price * $vat * .04 + .2` or `20 / $vat <= $price`

So if `$price >= 20 / $vat` then `$profit >= 1`.

To do specifically what you asked:

```
do {
    $profit = $price * $vat * .04 + .2;
    $price = $price + .1;
} while ($profit < 1);
```

Comment: But what i need to do is if $profit is less than 0, add 10p to my price and then re-evaluate from the start again. once $profit is greater than 1 then stop.